# Will a temporary file become persistent when I move it?

Tags: java, android, file, persistence, temp

My question is pretty straight forward. When I create a temporary file in android (using [File#createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File))), and I move that file to another directory (from /cache to /files of my application storage), will that file become persistent? Or is there a way to make it persistent? Or do I have to copy it and delete the original?

Answer (score 3):

The variant of `createTempFile` you gave requires specification of a containing directory for the file. If that directory is within operating-system managed temporary file store (such as `/tmp` in a Unix-like system), then you must move (copy) from the temp hierarchy to a "regular" directory location. But, if the specified directory is already outside of such a place, then you're fine.

The `File` class helps to abstract the idea of "OS Managed Temporary File Storage" by providing [File#createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))  so the code doesn't need to know (or figure out) an appropriate OS-temp directory (the Java runtime does that for you). Such files are created in an OS-Managed temp directory, which would need copying out to become permanent.

Also, consider that the "temp-ness" of temporary files is typically that they don't survive a system restart (often, they don't even survive a shutdown). Thus, temp files are already permanent-during-the-OS-life; if you need permanence across restart, then you would either create your temps in a persistent location in the first place, or be sure to move (copy) them there.

But then, I wonder, in what way are they "temporary" files in the first place?

Comment: I had a problem where I could not share bitmaps across activities, so I dumped them (along with other data) into one file. Now for the 2nd activity this file is temporary, since its only to pass data to the first activity. But the first activity then has to store this exact file somewhere else.

Comment: The thing is that the second activity doesn't know where to put it, so it stores it in a temporary file and the first one then decides where to put it.